# Minimum number of training examples needed for decision trees

Tags: probability, decision-tree, training-data, lower-bound

How can I measure the minimum number of training examples needed for a decision tree if I know node number, error rate and probability? Is there any formula for that?

Comment: This question is off topic for SO and more suitable for stats.stackexchange.com. That said, to get started you can look at a fixed tree structure and investigate how the remaining free parameters (which are just bin proportions) vary with the number of cases falling into each bin. I guess that's equivalent to estimating a binomial proportion for each bin. The bins which receive few cases will have high variance, but then again, bins with few cases don't count for much in the over all error rate. From there you'll have to think about letting the bins move around. Good luck and have fun.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is an exact way to know the needed training examples , just keep training and counting the number of examples ( you can make a counter in the loop ) with seeing the accuracy and loss , when you start getting in an accuracy of 70% and more then you can say that's a minimum needed

Comment: No, I need a theoretical answer if there is any formula. Not after training and testing.

Comment: @T2020 i understand man , but due to my experience on ML i can tell u that's a problem which cannot be answered by a theorical formula , because models are always different from each other so the data analyst have always to experience things to decide , we cant decide without experiencing accuracy and loss